# Using PageDown Editor (Formely WMD) but how do I get the value in HTML?

Tags: asp.net, pagedown

I'm using PageDown editor and I've got the following markup in my asp.net page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" runat="server">
            <div class="wmd-panel">
                <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
                <textarea id="wmd_input" class="wmd-input" runat="server"></textarea>
                <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
                var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
                editor1.run();
            })();
            </script>
            <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Set"></asp:button><asp:button id="Button2" runat="server" Text="Get"></asp:button><asp:label id="Label1" runat="server">Label</asp:label></form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

It results in the following look:

[image]

So I have a server side event that simply gets the value stored and assigns it to a label just so I can see what I am getting back:

`Me.Label1.Text = Me.wmd_input.Value`

So if I have something like `**test**` in my text area box (which shows up in bold) I want to be able to click the "Get" button and get back something to this effect `<b>test</b>` and not `**test**`.  Right now I am getting back `**test**` is there any way to get back `<b>test</b>`, the HTML markup instead?

Comment: Can you please post your code behind?

Comment: What code behind that is it...

Answer (score 1):

Use `.makeHtml("markdown text")` on client side

For your case

```
    converter1.makeHtml("*Hello World*")
```

To get Html value on server side use server side implementation of markdown like [MarkDown Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) or you can use hidden input field.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" runat="server">
        <div class="wmd-panel">
            <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
            <textarea id="wmd_input" class="wmd-input" runat="server"></textarea>
            <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
            var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
            editor1.run();
        })();
        function SetHidden(){
            var hidden = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenMarkdow.ClientID %>');
            var textArea = document.getElementById('<%= wmd_input.ClientID %>');
            var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
            hidden.value = converter1.makeHtml(textArea.value);
            return true;
        }



        </script>
        <asp:HiddenField id="HiddenMarkdown" runat="server"/>
        <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Set"></asp:button><asp:button id="Button2" runat="server" Text="Get" OnClick="SetHidden()"></asp:button><asp:label id="Label1" runat="server">Label</asp:label></form>
</body>
```

Comment: This wont help though how do I get it to the server side as html?

Comment: I know I can do ` var html = converter1.makeHtml(d.value); alert(html);` but how do I snatch this on the server side for processing...

Comment: You can use a hidden field and assign that value to a hidden field. Post that hidden field to the server

Comment: I tried that as well I tried `document.getElementById('hdnField').value =html` and it did not assign anything.  You are talking about a server side hidden field right?  I tried that no luck...

Comment: You can also use server side implementation of markdown like markdown sharp

Comment: I dont know what you are talking about, I just want to assign the value to a server side control so I can access it in my code behind.  Please post an example if possible for what I have.